# Updating the GSVIEW rather than open a new one

Tags: viewers, ps

I am using CTeX 2.9.2. After I use LaTeX+DVIPS+GSView, I used to get an updated GSView window. However, after I changed my computer and install a new CTeX, whenever I use LaTeX+DVIPS+GSView, I got a new GSView window, which is annoying as I have to shut down every old page.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes switching to LaTeX+PDF workflow